# Why does vscode ask to save changes?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am on version 1.30.0 , how can i fix the annoying question: do you want to save changes? I am using git so that takes care of my files already.

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense. Note that Git tracks file contents, and as such, the changes really must be saved to file before Git can take care of them.

Comment: related: [Why don't other programs see the changes I made to a file in VS Code until I save those changes?](/q/76984829/11107541)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want `code` to autosave, you must turn it on in your settings.

You can open settings going to `File/Preferences` in windows or `Code/Preferences` in Mac.

To turn on autosave, search for the option "Auto Save" or the write `"files.autoSave": "afterDelay"` in you `settings.json` file. You should also take a look at the option "Prompt to save files before commit", or `"git.promptToSaveFilesBeforeCommit": false` in the file.

Comment: Does not work for me. It keeps asking for saving unsaved files anyway, even though after I removed `~/.config/Code/User/data/settings.json`. Really confusing.

Answer (score 0):

when another program changed something in your file, vscode has another text not like in real file that git changed it previously so it asked you  to save for new